# Permission denied from bash

Tags: permissions

when I want to run a program(f.e., ./name.c) bash writes that permission denied. Yesterday everything was OK, I don't know what happened

Comment: at the very least, please do an `ls -l` on the file you are trying to execute and paste that information in your post.

Comment: `name.c` sounds like it might be a source code file, rather than an executable program: are you sure that you aren't supposed to compile it (e.g. `gcc -o name name.c`) and then run the resulting binary, `./name`?

Answer (score 2):

Compile the file first:

```
gcc name.c -o name.out
```

Then run the compiled binary:

```
./name.out
```